# summation in python

Tags: class, python-3.x

I am getting an error....and I know what I'm doing wrong, but not sure how to fix it. I understand I can't add a string to a integer...Any ideas, I'd be grateful!

```
    self.variables['gas'] = 'gas'+add
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

My code:

```
class Cars:        
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.variables = kwargs

    def set_Variable(self, k, v):
        self.variables[k] = v

    def get_Variable(self, k):
        return self.variables.get(k, None)     

    def add_gas(self, add, gas):
        self.variables['gas'] = gas+add


def main():
    mercedes = Cars(gas = 3)
    print (mercedes.get_Variable('gas'))
    print(mercedes.add_gas(4))


if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: Your traceback and your example code do not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method add_gas needs two arguments, you're only passing one to the function. Also you are printing the returning value though there is no return in the function.

This one worked for me:

```
class Cars:        
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.variables = kwargs

    def set_Variable(self, k, v):
        self.variables[k] = v

    def get_Variable(self, k):
        return self.variables[k]     

    def add_gas(self, add):
        self.variables['gas'] +=add

def main():
    mercedes = Cars(gas = 3)
    print (mercedes.get_Variable('gas'))
    mercedes.add_gas(4)
    print (mercedes.get_Variable('gas'))
    print ('There are %s gallons of gas in the car.' % mercedes.get_Variable('gas'))


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Comment: oh man, I see how I messed that up...ok, this makes sense. I always get tangled in the syntax....Thank you.

Comment: How can I print 'There currently are x gallons of  gas in the car' where x is (mercedes.get_Variable('gas')). I can't find anywhere the syntax for this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I see two independent problems with your code:

- In your error message you showed this line:

  ```
  self.variables['gas'] = 'gas'+add
  ```

  While in your code, the line is this:

  ```
  self.variables['gas'] = gas+add
  ```

  That are two different meanings. The first tries to concat the variable `add` to the string `'gas'` which will fail as `add` is an integer and Python won’t convert integers to strings implicitely (the error told you that). So you would want to do `'gas' + str(add)`.
- In your `main` function, you call the `add_gas` method like this:

  ```
  mercedes.add_gas(4)
  ```

  But you actually defined the method with two parameters, `add` and `gas`, so this will fail.

What I think is what you want to do is to increase the `self.variables['gas']` value by `add` when the method is called, so you would want to write your method like this:

```
def add_gas(self, add):
    self.variables['gas'] = self.variables['gas'] + add
```

Note that you can shorten that using the `+=` operator to just this:

```
def add_gas(self, add):
    self.variables['gas'] += add
```

And finally, I don’t know why you would want to use a dictionary for your locale instance variables, but unless you have a good reason to do that, why not just define a `gas` property for your car type?

Comment: How can I print 'There currently are x gallons of gas in the car' where x is (mercedes.get_Variable('gas')). I can't find anywhere the syntax for this.

Comment: the reason why i don't define a property gas, is because my class Car is more complicated than just gas...it has many other properties, so I am using the kwargs to add them as I need them too....otherwise I'd have an abundance of getters and setters.

Comment: You can use `print 'There are currently %s gallons' % mercedes.get_Variable('gas')`. See [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Comment: Also, in Python you don’t write explicit getter and setter methods, you just directly access the properties. So you would do `mercedes.gas` or `mercedes.color` etc. Also if your class takes so many (unknown) properties, you should really rethink if you are designing your application correctly. A class shouldn’t be so “flexible” in terms of properties. And the way you implement it, it’s more just a dictionary.

Comment: Totally agree with you on that.